# How to stack two images and center in the middle

Tags: html, css

I want the images to be centered  and I need two of the images to be stacked up on each other in the center. I have logo on the left and nav bar on the right

```css
.projImg {
  margin: 0;
}

.projImg img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  <div class="mainProj">
    <main>
        <figure class="projImg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/UiAiZYm.jpg" alt="projectImage1">
        </figure>

        <figure class="projImg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/4F4Agjz.jpg" alt="projectImage2">
        </figure>

        <figure class="projImg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/GncQ8QI.jpg" alt="projectImage3">
        </figure>

        <figure class="projImg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MGkSJza.jpg" alt="projectImage4">
        </figure>
    </main>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you share a snap of the desired final result?

Comment: Is this something you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/2hjxszck/7/

Answer (score 0):

Use following code...

```css
.projImg {
  text-align:center;
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
}

.projImg img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="mainProj">
    <main>
        <figure class="projImg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/UiAiZYm.jpg" alt="projectImage1">
        </figure>

        <figure class="projImg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/4F4Agjz.jpg" alt="projectImage2">
        </figure>

        <figure class="projImg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/GncQ8QI.jpg" alt="projectImage3">
        </figure>

        <figure class="projImg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MGkSJza.jpg" alt="projectImage4">
        </figure>
    </main>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.projImg {
  margin: 0;
}

.projImg img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;

}
```

use this CSS code to centralize your images.